# Add a modifiers uv project with python

Tags: python, modifiers, uv

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work?

I would like to use my object "Camera" as a projector in my modifier "UVProject"

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='UV_PROJECT')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].object = "Camera"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you are trying to set is a collection so you have to choose an index as you can have several projectors, use:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='UV_PROJECT')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].projectors[0].object = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
```

See [`bpy.types.UVProjectModifier`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.UVProjectModifier.html).